# CSS file is not getting loaded in HTML file. I am using Netbeans IDE

Tags: html, css

I am new to HTML and CSS and trying to load my CSS file in my HTML code with the help of reading multiple answers on Stack Overflow, but sadly not able to run this code as CSS file is not loading in my HTML code. Please, if someone can help or is there any error in my code.
My HTML code:

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <title>My favourite character</title>
        
        <link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
     
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Batman</h1>
        <h4>A silent guardian, A watchful protector, A dark knight</h4>
        <p>batman is the best man. He is <b>kind</b>. <br>He helps people like my neigbhours. 
            Batman is the alias of Bruce Wayne, a wealthy American playboy, philanthropist, and industrialist who resides in Gotham City. </p>
        <br><a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman" target = "_blank"> Click here</a> to know more about batman
       
        <h2>Unordered list</h2>
        <ul type = "square">
            <li>this is line 1</li>
            <li>this is line 2</li>
            <li>this is line 3</li>
            <li>this is line 4</li>
        </ul>
        <h2>Ordered list</h2>
        <ol type = "a">
            <li>this is line 1</li>
            <li>this is line 2</li>
            <li>this is line 3</li>
            <li>this is line 4</li>
        </ol>
    </body>
</html>
```

My CSS file code-named style.css:

```css
body{ max-width:1000px;
    margin: auto;
    font-family:Robot;
    font-size:32px;
    color: yellow;
    background-color: black;
}
h4{
    font : italic small-caps bolder 28px arial, sans-serif;
}
```

Error it is giving:

It is showing failed to load resource

[image: 1]

Folder structure of my HTML and CSS file:

```
My first project: Site Root                     
    Site Root: index.html 
               style.css
               test.html
```

index.html and style.css files are in same folder(Site Root) or if it's not, please tell because I guess Site Root is a folder only.
Screenshot of my folder structure:[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w0fJt.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w0fJt.png)

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you please share your folder structure of HTML and CSS file as well?

Comment: Not much we can do from here. Is the path right? It implies that the HTML and CSS files are in the same location.

Comment: Yes HTML and CSS file are in the same location..do I need to change that? plz tell

Comment: Thankyou so much everyone , the issue is resolved..it was really amazing for me as it was the first doubt that I did put on StackOverflow. I can't describe the feeling of getting help from you all and actually the issue being resolved. Thank you so much everyone.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably a bad reference. Check if you have any typos or your file is in the same folder as your root.

Comment: My file is in the same folder as my html file. I have added my folder structure, plz check if u can

Comment: Thankyou so much everyone , the issue is resolved..it was really amazing for me as it was the first doubt that I did put on StackOverflow. I can't describe the feeling of getting help from you all and actually the issue being resolved. Thank you so much everyone.

Answer (score 0):

This can be due to your code structure. From what you have in your code you should have your css file in the same folders as the html file using it. If the css file is somewhere else you have to point to the location where the file is. For example: if the file is inside a folder called css your reference should be

```
<link href="./css/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

Comment: Folder structure of my HTML and CSS file:    My first project:   Site Root: index.html , style.css, test.html

Comment: Thankyou so much everyone , the issue is resolved..it was really amazing for me as it was the first doubt that I did put on StackOverflow. I can't describe the feeling of getting help from you all and actually the issue being resolved. Thank you so much everyone.

Comment: You welcome, don't forget to vote the answer that helped you. That's the best way here to say thanks :)